# Spring Cloud Stream vs Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm developing an application that consumes messages from an exchange and it can publish to one of the multiple exchanges based on the input message transformation result.

I am trying to decide whether to go with sprrimg amqp or spring cloud stream.

What would be apt for this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Spring Cloud Stream (its Rabbit Binder) is a higher-level abstraction on top of Spring AMQP.

It is more opinionated and performs some configuration automatically.

Comment: is it possible to override the configs?
Example, if i create the a ConneectionFactory bean, will the spring cloud stream use the bean i defined automatially? (as spring amqp uses it?)

Comment: Yes; it will use an overridden connection factory. It autowires it so there must be only one, or one must be marked `@Primary`.